# ModelState not validating nested models after editing in controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have nested ViewModels like these two:

```
public class FirstViewModel
{
    public SecondViewModel SecondViewModel { get; set; }
}

public class SecondViewModel
{
    [Range(1, 12)]
    public int month { get; set; }
}
```

If I put `month = 13;` and then call `ModelState.IsValid` (in the controller) the validation is always `true`.

**Edit:**

This is the Controller:

```
public ActionResult Create()
{
    return PartialView(new FirstViewModel);    
}

public HttpStatusCodeResult Create (FirstViewModel viewModel){

    viewModel.SecondViewModel = new SecondViewModel();
    viewModel.SecondViewModel.month = 13;

    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        return new HttpStatusCodeResult(200);
    }
    else
    {
        return new HttpStatusCodeResult(304);
    }
}
```

I'm making an abstraction of the problem, those aren't the real variables.

Comment: Would you show us your Controller **GET** and **Post** method?

Comment: Any update will help us finding a solution. Show us your Model and ModelState when you didn't set the month.

Comment: There is no **Validate** Property at **ModelState**. How you compile your project? You should have get some error.

Comment: Probably is an extension method.

Comment: I have deleted my answer as you didn't provide any more data and probably it isn't suitable for you. Try to read this post: https://lostechies.com/jimmybogard/2011/09/07/building-forms-for-deep-view-model-graphs-in-asp-net-mvc/

Comment: Just updated with more info!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your question states you *"call ModelState.Validate"* in you controller. There is no such method, so I assume you mean `if (ModelState.IsValid)`.

The first step in the model binding process is that the parameters of your method are initialized, in your case a new instance of `FirstViewModel`. Then the values of the model are set based on form data, route values, query string values etc. and any validation errors associated with the properties of your model are added to `ModelState`.

Subsequently modifying the value of properties in your model has no affect on `ModelState`, so if the initial value of `month` is valid, then `ModelState.IsValid` will return true irrespective of setting `viewModel.SecondViewModel.month = 13;`

If you want to re-validate your model, your need to use [TryUpdateModel](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460189(v=vs.118).aspx) which returns a `bool` indicating if the update succeeded

```
public HttpStatusCodeResult Create (FirstViewModel viewModel)
{
  viewModel.SecondViewModel = new SecondViewModel();
  viewModel.SecondViewModel.month = 13;
  if (TryUpdateModel(viewModel)
  {
    return new HttpStatusCodeResult(200);
  }
  else
  {
    return new HttpStatusCodeResult(304);
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I updated the code with the correct method. Is there a method similar to TryUpdateModel that returns the errors with their messages? I want to return a Json with all the errors.

Comment: Once you have called `TryUpdateModel` then the errors are added to `ModelState`. There are a number of options you could consider, for example, `var errors = ModelState.Keys.Where(k => ModelState[k].Errors.Count > 0).Select(k => new { propertyName = k, errorMessage = ModelState[k].Errors[0].ErrorMessage });` will give you a collection of all the property names that have errors and the first error associated with them, so you could use `return Json(errors);` and then loop through them on the client.

Answer (score 0):

As the SecondViewModel property of the FirstViewModel class is null, it will not be validated. Try adding a required attribute to the property:

```
public class FirstViewModel
{
    [Required]
    public SecondViewModel SecondViewModel { get; set; }
}

public class SecondViewModel
{
    [Range(1, 12)]
    public int month { get; set; }
}
```

**EDIT**

Based on your update, I agree with @StephenMuecke. You can not instantiate a class yourself and expect the framework to validate it for you. TryUpdateModel is what you are looking for in this case or you have to let the framework instantiate the class for you. You would need to pass in SecondViewModel.month=13 somewhere in your request in order to see that in action.

Comment: Or perhaps try to instantiate the SecondViewModel in the get ?

Comment: When I add ´required´ the ModelState.IsValid is false and the exception says  SecondViewModel is null. You can si the controller in the original question!

Answer (score 0):

You can validate you model anytime using [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd411772(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
Validator.TryValidateObject().
```

or, just for one property, see [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.validator.tryvalidateproperty(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
Validator.TryValidateProperty()
```

Let say you have class Address

```
public class Address
{
    [Required]
    public string Address2 { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string ZipCode{ get; set; }
}
```

You could use this snippet to validate your object. All the errors will be in the "results" varibale.

```
var addresse = new Address() { Street = null, ZipCode = null};
var context = new ValidationContext(addresse, null, null);
var results = new List<ValidationResult>();
bool isValid = Validator.TryValidateObject(addresse, context, results, true);
```

Comment: Not sure about performance. I would recommend to test performance if it is in a loop!